# Commons MultiKeyMap vs nested HashMaps

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap, multikey

I have to associate an Object to a n keys, such as  --> .
I am considering using [Commons MultiKeyMap](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/map/MultiKeyMap.html) or nesting HashMaps (such as `Map<K1,Map<K2,Map<K3,O1>>>`).

**Question**: I was wondering which alternative generates the least memory overhead.

**Note**: I am not particularly concerned about speed of put and get.

Comment: As for Generics, commons collection 4.0 has been around for a while: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/map/MultiKeyMap.html

Other than that: Why don't you try both variations and take some measurements?

Comment: @Ray Thanks for pointing out the new release. I edit the question accordingly.